# How can I find files with a long first line?

Tags: files, find, wc

currently I have a problem with a server. One user who is hosting a lot of sites got hacked and some of his php files were modified. Now I want to get a list of the infected files and also want to check if he cleaned the whole mess.

The common thing between the infected files is that the first line is very long. So I'd like to find every php file on the server that has a min length of 1000 chars.

Well, I can find all php files with "find" and get with "head -n 1" the first line and count the chars with "wc -m".

But how can I combine it together?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but truthfully, you should nuke it from orbit and restore from backup.  (You have backups, of course?)

Comment: I have backups, I don't think, the owner of the sites have any ;)
But I also want some kind of a script, that is able to detect the infections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with just `find` and `awk`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -size +1000c -exec awk '
    FNR > 1 {nextfile}
    length >= 1000 {print FILENAME}' {} +
```

The `awk` script skips to next file after the first line of every file.  It prints the filename of the current file if the current line is >= 1000 characters long.

Comment: Or `length >= 1000`. Note that [`nextfile` is in a  few other awk implementations as well](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607), you can add a `-size +1000c` to avoid the check on small files.

Comment: yep, just figured that out myself while testing with `original-awk` and `mawk`.  `nextfile` isn't much of a portability problem, the problem was the regexp with `{1000,}`   the `-size` is a useful improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one using `find` and `grep` :

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep '.\{1000\}' {} +
```

Comment: that will check every line of each file, not just the first line of each.

Comment: @cas yes, you are right. In that case your answer is much more better than mine. +1 for yours.